# Payroll application - Complex SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

SQL FIDDLE HERE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c7f7/5**

I am building a payroll database and until now everything was perfect. One vital concept that I did not address from the start was when an employee has a pay grade change, will that be reflected from the date the pay grade changed? Previously the query would just go by whatever pay grade the employee had next to his name, but that is inaccurate if his rate changes (for example) every day of the week?

With the help of others, I have got as far as the SQL Fiddle above, however the result is not reflecting the correct answer. At present with the 'where' clause in that fiddle, it uses the incorrect pay rate from the historyemployeepay table. It should be selecting the 'null' ToDate row and using that as the base rate?? Can someone show me what is going wrong?

Comment: What you need is a DBA :p

Comment: haha! yes but this is a project I need to complete...

Comment: Create an SQL Fiddle (sqlfiddle.com) if you can. That way it is easier for people to work on the problem.

Comment: Maybe you could save users current rate always with the employee hours

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b9a7/6

Comment: Your historyemployeepay table... one record of 10, another of 112.  Not possible for 112 hours in a given day... Type-o? or other.  As for a pay rate change per the employee... how/where are you keeping that information.  If they are normal rate X on Dec 10 and rate X2 on Dec 11, then is there a record that has the other rate too that reflects a pay raise such as overtime pay?

Comment: Additionally, you should probably have a pay type table with the enumerated list of values and just store the key types from that, and get the description as you need it later.  And column names, I would consider horrendous having spaces, periods, percent, slashes.  Things like that should be in the reporting output and not an actual column name.  You open yourself to horrible readability (IMO).

Comment: value in the historyemployeepay table is for pay rate value, so it would be 'hours' * 112. I made one a larger value so that it would produce a very different result, for testing purposes

Comment: I have changed the history table a little, didn't realise I had the wrong pic up until now, thanks! Please see above :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jacob offered an option, I too would make some changes to normalization too.

```
Table PayCodes
PayCodeID  PayCodeDescription     timesBase  timesOtherRate timesMealRate
1          01 Ordinary            1.0        0.0            0.0
2          02 Overtime            1.5        0.0            0.0
3          03 Overtime            2.0        0.0            0.0
4          78 Crib                .333       0.0            0.0
5          CZ Meal Allowance PS   0.0        0.0            1.0
6          86Y Sick with Cert     1.0        0.0            0.0 
etc...
```

Then, in your hourly table which data entry would be data driven to get the corresponding paycodes, save the internal ID Code vs the hard-code word references.  You could even build another column for a "PayStubCaption" if you didn't want to show any cryptic references.

For your employee pay rate history, have the fields include begin/end dates since it is a rare occasion (once a year?? MAYBE twice??)  Have both begin and end date of the given rate and also include (in this example the 3 rates you track..

```
PayHistoryID  EmployeeID  FromDate    ToDate     BaseRate  OtherRate  MealRate
1             84238       2012-10-10  2013-9-30  10.0      15.0       3.5      
2             84238       2013-10-1   (current)  14.0      21.0       6      
...
```

These can significantly help simplify querying downstream...

As for adding to the query for the per rate to be applied, that will become a simple join provided you dont allow bad data, such as a from/to range on one record crosses that of another for the same person...

```
select
     ...
     sum( case/when...  PRT.BaseRate ) as ...
   from
      other join tables...
         JOIN PayRatesTable PRT
            on employeehours_copy.EmployeeID PRT.EmployeeID
           AND PRT.FromDate <= employeehours_copy.Worked
           AND ( PRT.ToDate IS NULL OR employeehours_copy.Worked <= PRT.ToDate )
```

Notice for simplified reading, I've aliased the sample "PayRateTable" to PRT.  Then just
use the "PRT.BaseRate" or other rate, meals rate for each computation instead of the rate that is possibly in your employee table.  You should also get in the habit of qualifying all your table.column (or alias.column) for ambiguity problems, especially if ever a join where the column names are the same in each table.

Comment: Part 1 of what you said: I receive all the data 'as is' from different sources, hence the reason I have chosen to not create the table 'PayCodes' :).

Part 2: I get what you mean, will adjust now but I still do not know how to get a query to check between those dates and use that rate when necessary.. How do you do this?!

Comment: @atomapps, revised to join new pay rate table for you.

Comment: It's not picking up correctly Mr DRapp... I think there is an error in your code... Not sure how I could solve as it just doesn't seem to work correctly in the 'where' clause. Please have a look at this SQL Fiddle? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c7f7/1

Comment: I updated the sqlfiddle to show just the rate parts at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c7f7/5   Notice, I just did 4 queries so I could see the parts from each table, then the join -- REGARDLESS of the summation, just to prove the context of the query/join result.  I'll try to look at it more later.

Comment: Thank you DRapp, much appreciated. This would be the last major modification to my project so I can complete... I love database development in a networks role haha...

Comment: I had the wrong coding! here is the modification: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c7f7/7

Comment: @atomapps, so from your latest SQLFiddle, what is it NOT doing that you still need help on.

Comment: It's doing everything as per what I require, for now. I have accepted your answer and up-voted as well :). Thank you DRapp I really am grateful.

Comment: @atomapps, ok, just was not sure

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to modularize a little more.  If this were my project I would create a procedure that processes each time slot.

Let's say Bob clocks in from 8am to 5pm on January 1st and 11am to 6pm on January 2nd.  On Jan 1st, Bob makes $10hr and on the 2nd he makes $20.

Our data may look like

```
Payrange
--------
Dec 20 2012 - Jan 01 2013 | $10
Jac 02 2013 - Jan 30 2013 | $20

Clock
-----
Jan 01 2013 | 9 hours
Jan 02 2013 | 7 hours
```

With this information, you can sum each row of the clock **after** you multiply it against its corresponding payrange.

Comment: Create a procedure... how do I do that???? I have only got as far as being able to reproduce the values without the history table... I've edited above... Would you be able to show me how to write a procedure for this? thanks :)